# Block Automatic Full Screen

Tags: 18.04

When the title bar of a frame hits the top or the side, it snaps open to full screen.

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false
```

turns off maximizing a window when it's dragged up against the top bar. Unfortunately, it also turns off dragging a window left or right to maximize windows vertically while resizing them to half the screen width.

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling
```

resets the default.

Comment: not in kubuntu: `No such schema “org.gnome.mutter”`

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on the Desktop environment you are using. Personally, I use Mate. In case of Mate you need to go to the control center and you will find something like "Mate Tweak". I think it is in the section Windows in Window Behavior, where you can disable window snapping. So, depending on the Desktop environment you use, you might want to look for the "Tweak" in your control center.

Comment: In addition to that: you must select Marco as window manager in the same Mate Tweak. If you choose Compiz there is no way to turn auto tiling off.